# How can I round this number up to the nearest 10,000th?

Tags: python, list, tuples

So, I want to round the output to the nearest 10,000th (the output will be printed in decimals). However, when I used `round()`, nothing happened. What should I change in my code so that it prints the right output?

**Edit** So this is my output from the code

```
2.4586597040905134
```

and what I want the output to look like is the same thing but rounded to the 10,000th place so, I want the output should look like this,

```
2.45866
```

Like when I used round(), the same 2.4586597040905134 came up. Are there any issues with syntax for assertion for this?

Comment: why dont you use the [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69855361/how-can-i-implement-a-function-to-print-out-for-all-similar-strings/69855764#69855764)

Comment: that answer is great but I'm not allowed to import stuff for this 'assignment'. So I wrote up this code and now encountered this issue (the question)

Comment: @balderman thank u for taking ur time off to answer that one though. I hv upvoted it.

Comment: The `import` are coming from core python libraries. You should add this constraint to the post.

Comment: Add an example of what **exactly** you need. If the problem is to convert a number - share the original value and the desired value.

Comment: @Bruffff That is exactly what `round(value, 5)` does. Why doesn't round work for you? E.g. show what you tried with `round`.

Comment: Aha sorry I see. You pass to round the number of digits, not which number length you want (e.g. `5`, not `100000000`)

Comment: @Megaing ohhhh, yea I got it now, thank u very much

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to round to 2 decimals with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20457038/how-to-round-to-2-decimals-with-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the [docs](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/round-function-python/)

See below

```
num = 2.4586597040905134
num = round(num,5)
print(num)
```

output

```
2.45866
```